# Hide or Add Button in Constraint Layout based on some condition

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, android-button, android-constraintlayout

[image]

I have this layout on `Fragment`. It has 3 `Buttons`. Below `Button3` there is one `TextView`.When this layout is set I am checking some conditions. If that condition is satisfied I am showing the `Button3`. But if the condition is not satisfied I need to hide the button.
This is how the layout looks after hiding `Button3`

[image]

It appears to be a lot of blank space between the `TextView` and `Button2` when the button is hidden but in my XML layout, it is present there. How to avoid this so that it doesn't appear blank space?

This is code for XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myConstraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/allscreenbackground">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/tabIndicator"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Table: "
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tableName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.03"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tableName"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/full_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.04"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/full_name"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tableName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:text="Pax -"
        android:textColor="@color/textTitles"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/people"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Occupied Since :"
        android:textColor="@color/textTitles"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/lapsedTime"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/people"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/textTitles"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lapsedTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/textTitles"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.06"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.18" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shift"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yes_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.283" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/end"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yes_button"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.387" />


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/freeThisTable"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yes_button"
        android:text="Button 3"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/isBday"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/birthday" />

    <ImageView
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/isAniversary"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.78"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ring_new" />

    <TextView
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/isBdayText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textTitles"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline32"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.64" />

    <TextView
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/isAniversaryText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textTitles"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline32"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.76" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="100dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your XML here.

Comment: android:visibility="gone" or view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the spaces of the object use it:

```
boolean myCondition = true;

if(myCondition) {
    Button3.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
}
else {
    Button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of incorrect constraint. You have constrained most of your views TOP to parent and set bias to align it. Instead of that, do align under your consecutive views. It will work as your requirement.

For better understanding, I have edited your xml file. Replace and check it out.

```
<........./>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    .............../>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/freeThisTable"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/yes_button"
    android:text="Button 3"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/end" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/isBday"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/isBdayText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/isBdayText"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/birthday" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/isAniversary"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/isAniversaryText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/isAniversaryText"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ring_new" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/isBdayText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="@color/textTitles"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline32"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/freeThisTable" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/isAniversaryText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/textTitles"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline32"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/isBdayText" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline32"
    .............. />
```